# Linear Combination of Linearly Independent Vectors

Tags: vectors

I would like to know if a linear combination of linearly independent vectors, forms linearly independent vectors.

For example I have $\{\mathbf{a}_1, \mathbf{a}_2\}$ which are known to be linearly independent vectors. I am trying to find if $\{\mathbf{a}_1 + \mathbf{a}_2, \mathbf{a}_1 - \mathbf{a}_2\}$ are linearly independent as well.

My reasoning is as follows:

If $\{\mathbf{a}_1, \mathbf{a}_2\}$ are linearly independent, the equation $k_1 \mathbf{a}_1 + k_2 \mathbf{a}_2 = \mathbf{0}$ is satisfied by $k_1=k_2=0$, by definition of a set of linearly independent vectors.

I let $k_1=x_1+x_2$ and $k_2=x_1-x_2$ and go through the following steps.

$$(x_1+x_2) \mathbf{a}_1 + (x_1-x_2) \mathbf{a}_2 = \mathbf{0}$$

$$x_1 \mathbf{a_1} + x_2 \mathbf{a}_1 + x_1 \mathbf{a}_2 - x_2 \mathbf{a}_2 = \mathbf{0}$$

$$x_1 (\mathbf{a}_1 + \mathbf{a}_2) + x_2(\mathbf{a}_1 - \mathbf{a}_2) = \mathbf{0}$$

Hence these vectors satisfy the form of linearly independent vectors.

Hence if $\{\mathbf{a}_1, \mathbf{a}_2\}$ are linearly independent, $\{\mathbf{a}_1 + \mathbf{a}_2, \mathbf{a}_1 - \mathbf{a}_2\}$ are also linearly independent.

Sorry if I'm up the wrong tree, I would appreciate some assistance, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is backwards: in order to prove that $\{\mathbf{a}_1 + \mathbf{a}_2, \mathbf{a}_1 - \mathbf{a}_2\}$ is linearly independent, you should start from
$$
k_1(\mathbf{a}_1 + \mathbf{a}_2)+k_2(\mathbf{a}_1 - \mathbf{a}_2)=\mathbf{0}
$$
that becomes
$$
(k_1+k_2)\mathbf{a}_1+(k_1-k_2)\mathbf{a}_2=\mathbf{0}
$$
Since $\{\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2\}$ is linearly independent, we obtain
$$
\begin{cases}
k_1+k_2=0\\
k_1-k_2=0
\end{cases}
$$
that immediately gives $k_1=k_2=0$. So the set is linearly independent.

It's not necessarily true for *any* linear combination: for instance
$$
\{\mathbf{a_1}+\mathbf{a}_2,2\mathbf{a_1}+2\mathbf{a}_2\}
$$
is not linearly independent.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thank you so much for the clarification. Thank you for fixing my syntax as well, I will try to improve for next time!